# Where are defined options_container template in Magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

I have this code in my form.phtml

```
/**
* Product view template
*
* @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View
*/
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $block->hasOptions() && $block->getOptionsContainer() == 'container2'): ?>
    <?php echo $block->getChildChildHtml('options_container'); ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

And here is the layout catalog_product_view

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="MM_Catalog::css/magnific-popup.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="product.info">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">MM_Catalog::product/view/form.phtml</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

This works, but I need to add more fields into the printed fieldset. But I don't know where and how I am supposed to specify these fields that are printed into the fieldset.

Thanks for your help

Comment: you want to put field after custom options am I right?

Comment: I want to add fields inside the `$block->getChildChildHtml('options_container')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the default layout file catalog_product_view.xml you will find that

"**options_container**" contains another secondary block inside it named as "**product_options_wrapper**" which contains the following template

```
Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/wrapper.phtml
```

You can add more fields here by overriding it in your custom module .

"**product_options_wrapper**" contains another secondary block "**product_options**" which is responsible for option's rendering.

So if you want to add more fields according to options you can find corresponding templates for each options over there like,for Text input

```
Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/text.phtml
```

You can add fields in this templates by overriding it in your custom module.